# Constructing a bijection between intervals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

So I am trying to solve questions below

1. Let $A = \{(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\ldots): \alpha_i \in
     \{0,1\}, i \in N\}$, i.e., $A$ is the infinite cartesian product of the
   set $\{0,1\}$. Show that $A$ is uncountable.
2. Prove that the intervals $[0,\infty)$ and $(-1,4)$ have the same cardinality
   by constructing a bijection between the two sets.

For the second question I tried to construct a bijection between $[0,\infty)$ and $[-1,4)$, but couldn't go any farther.

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Hint: There is a bijection from $[0,\infty)$ to $(0,\infty)$. Send $0$ to $1$, $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$, and so on. For any other $x$, send $x$ to $x$.

Comment: Please ask one question per thread. Moreover, both questions have been asked before, so be sure to search the site before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, this is a standard example for cantors diagonal counting,

the second one would be much easier with  Cantor Schröder Bernstein. If you want a bijection we construct at first a bijection from $[0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$, use the identity on every non integer and for the integers add $1$. After this we can use the function $\frac{1}{x+1}$ to map $(0,\infty)$ on the set $(0,1)$. Finding a bijection between to open sets is now quite easy so you should be able to handle the rest.